# Finding Excel cell location based on value in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I am working on a script that finds the row of an excel sheet based on one of its column values, then writes to the cell. I am doing so with **ImportExcel**

```
$sheet = ImportExcel $path -worksheetname $worksheet
$row = $sheet | where $column -eq $value 
$row.different_column = $new_value #this is the cell I would like to change the value of
```

Now I know I can easily change the cell value with open-excelpackage, but it requires the location value of the cell. Is there a way I can get the index of the row queried for? If not, can I just directly change it a specific way?

I've tried most of the importexcel functions, but am open to use another package if necessary.

Comment: Each row should have a row property : $row.Row